# debugging next.js with vscode debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, next.js

I have installed a project using [create-next-app](https://github.com/segmentio/create-next-app).
I need to debug the server side rendering using my editor: vscode. So i have visited [vscode-recipes - how to debug next.js app](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Next-js).

I have made a slight change to the recipe so I won't have to install `Next` globally.

that's my `launch.json` config file:

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Next: Node",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-inspect"],
      "port": 9229,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
```

While i'm running it I get the following error:

`Error: Use env variable NODE_OPTIONS instead: NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect" next dev`

I'm trying to change `runtimeArgs` to following command that should work:
`"runtimeArgs": ["NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect"]` and I am getting other error:

```
No such directory exists as the project root: /Users/username/with-redux-thunk-app/NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect
```

How I can I correctly express `"NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect"` so it works with vscode debugger?

Comment: This post helped me A LOT: https://hackernoon.com/what-is-nextjs-and-how-to-debug-it-82523t65

Comment: There is an official Next.js debugging page now: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging

Answer (score 9):

I managed to debug it without any additional arguments, my config:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this solution too but its showing "Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root"
my folder structure :
backend
frontend
 .next
 cmponents
 node_modules
 pages
 public
 .env.local
 packge-lock-json
 pacakege.json
node_modules
.env
pacakge-lock-json
package.json

Answer (score 5):

Potential pitfalls:
If your next project is in **subfolder in your vscode workspace**, you should set `sourceMapPathOverrides`.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Example",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect", "node_modules/.bin/next", "dev"],
      "port": 9229,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/subfolder",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceRoot}/subfolder/*",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94300#issue-592746846)

You may also need a different type of source map, alter your next.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.devtool = 'cheap-module-eval-source-map';
    return config;
  }
};
```

Also, **Starting in version 9.3.1**, do not add the --inspect flag in any configuration - it is passed automatically through the next command.

[source](https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/debugging-in-vscode~f93e5e29-6cce-4b43-8fed-e5a6d302d04e?m=MTU4NDc5Nzg5MDUyNg==) with lots of info on topic.

Comment: it gives me error like :                                                                                                   Uncaught G:\VIVEK\PROJECTS\SOCIAL NETOWRK\frontend\node_modules\.bin\next:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Comment: my launch.json is                                                                                                                                  {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Example",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect", "node_modules/.bin/next", "dev"],
      "port": 9229,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceRoot}/frontend/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, there is my `launch.json` with small fixes from the vscode recipe you mentioned:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Next: Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Next: Node",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
        "env": {
            "NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect-brk"
        },
        "port": 9229,
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
],
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Next: Full",
        "configurations": ["Next: Node", "Next: Chrome"]
    }
]
}
```

The instructions are : Launch `"Next: Full"`, wait a moment to let time to Node to run Next. Then you can refresh the Chrome windows.

On track record, the debug on Node is OK for me, however the debug in Chrome is partial : I can break up on lines but can't see all variables, I still can't know why?

Comment: it gives me 
`Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root`

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me, no matter the framework:

at `launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach by Process ID",
      "port": 9229,
      "skipFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*", "<node_internals>/**"]
    },
```

at `package.json` scripts:

```
"dev:debug": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect 9229' next dev",
```

Answer (score 0):

08-2022 Review :

For me the issue was that I was able to debug pages files but was unable to debug a middleware.ts file,

1.This solved it :

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Next.js Node Debug",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
    "env": {
        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect"
    },
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "meteor://app/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*",
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*",
        "webpack://?:*/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
    }
  }
```

2.Working with Next.JS debug manual did not work (!)

Answer (score 0):

For me, on NextJS 14.0.1 with app router, default layout, latest Visual Studio Code, this worked for both frontend and backend:

```json
{
  "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
  "type": "node-terminal",
  "request": "launch",
  "command": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
  "serverReadyAction": {
    "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
    "uriFormat": "%s",
    "action": "debugWithChrome"
  }
},
```