# Unable to debug Next.JS app (server side) in VSCode (following official debug guide, using official starter template)

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, next.js

I'm trying to debug the server-side code of a Next.JS app using VSCode's debugger, but I'm unable to get any breakpoints to bind. Debugging using chrome's dev tools (via chrome://inspect) to attach to the debugger behaves as expected.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Generate a Next.JS app using `npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"` (as instructed at https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup).
2. Create a `launch.json` as described in https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging#debugging-with-vs-code
3. Run the `Next.js: debug server-side` debug task in VSCode
4. Set a breakpoint in e.g. `pages/index.js` (I set mine on the return statement inside the `Home` component).
5. Visit the homepage

**Expected behaviour**:

- VSCode binds the breakpoint (shows as red filled circle)
- When loading the homepage, the breakpoint should be hit

**Actual behaviour**:

- VSCode warns the breakpoint cannot be bound (see screenshot 1)
- When loading the homepage, the breakpoint is not hit

Additional info:
I tried adding an "attach" entry in `launch.json`. Starting this after manually running `npm run dev` gave me a bit more info - VSCode gives more hints about what's going on - see screenshots 2 & 3. Here's the attach entry:

```
{
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229,
  "request": "attach",
  "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
  "type": "node"
}
```

Am I missing some step or other? It's like the sourcemaps aren't working correctly or something?

**System info**

- Next.JS version 13.1.6
- VSCode version 1.75.0
- Node version: 18.7.0
- OS: Linux

[image: screenshot of VSCode showing an unbound breakpoint in a Next.JS app]
[image: screenshot of VSCode showing an unbound breakpoint with a link to troubleshooting, in a Next.JS app]
[image: screenshot of VSCode showing troubleshooting for a breakpoint in a Next.JS app]

**Other questions**

There are a couple other questions about debugging Next.JS server-side code with VSCode, but they're quite old now, and predate the official Next.JS documentation I follow in the steps to reproduce, so I'm not sure how relevant they are:

- [unable to debug Next.js app using visual code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001551/unable-to-debug-next-js-app-using-visual-code)
- [debugging next.js with vscode debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050061/debugging-next-js-with-vscode-debugger)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been resolved in the latest version of Next (13.4.19 at the time of writing).